# Django Makemigrations not working in version 1.10 after adding new table

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I added some table models in `models.py` for the first time running the app and then ran `python manage.py makemigrations` followed by `python manage.py migrate`. This works well but after adding two more tables it doesn't work again.

It created *migrations* for the changes made but when I run `python manage.py migrate` nothing happens. My new tables are not added to the database.

Things I have done:

1. Deleted all files in *migrations* folder and then run `python manage.py makemigrations`followed by `python manage.py migrate` but the new tables are not still not getting added to the database even though the new table models show in the migration that was created i.e **0001_initial.py**.
2. Deleted the database followed by the steps in 1 above but it still didn't solve my problem. Only the first set of tables get created.
3. Tried `python manage.py makemigrations app_name` but it still didn't help.

Comment: Do you have __init__.py in your migrations still?

Comment: Can we see the relevant portion of your `models.py`?

Comment: @KeithBailey yes I do. But at a point I deleted it too but it got recreated when I run `python manage.py makemigrations app_name`.

Comment: Try this.1 delete migrations but not init.py 2) also delete __cache__ folder.

Answer (score 1):

I have run into this problem before and found that running `manage.py` for specific tables in this fashion worked:

```
python manage.py schemamigration mytablename --auto
python manage.py migrate
```

Also make sure that your new table is listed under `INSTALLED_APPS` in your `settings.py`.

Comment: I have error when I run the first line. *Unknown command: schemamigration*

Comment: I had a typo. `schemamigration`, not `schemamigraton`.

Comment: You also may have to install `south` first (`pip install south`) and add `'south'` to `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your models?

Have you edited manage.py in any way?

Try deleting the migrations and the database again after ensuring that your models are valid, then run manage.py makemigrations appname and then manage.py migrate.

Answer (score -1):

You could try:

1. Deleted everything in the django-migrations table.
2. Deleted all files in migrations folder and then run python manage.py makemigrations followed by python manage.py migrate as you said.

If this doesn't work, try:

1. Deleted everything in the django-migrations table.
2. Deleted all files in migrations folder, use your old model.py to run python manage.py makemigrations followed by python manage.py migrate.
3. Add new model, run python manage.py makemigrations followed by python manage.py migrate again.